# Accessing arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

A couple questions about 2D arrays in C.

1. If I create an two dimensional array:

   ```
   int c[5][25];
   ```

   Then create a pointer to the beginning of the array:

   ```
   int *p = c;
   ```

   Edit: Changing the second line to:

   ```
   int (*p)[25] = c;
   ```

   worked. Will this still let me access the array in the following questions?
2. Would `*(c+26)` access the array at `c[1][1]`?

   I know in a one dimensional array like the following:

   ```
   double *p;
   double balance[10];

   p = balance;
   ```

   `*(balance + 4)` is the same as `balance[4]`, but wasn't sure if the memory is assigned "back to back" for a 2D array.
3. Can you access `c[1][1]` by doing something like `c[2][-24]`?

   Would be an odd way to do it, but I couldn't find anything addressing that specific scenario.
4. Would you be able to access `c[1][1]` by the statement `p[1][1]`?

   My guess would be no, since p is a pointer array.
5. Saw these examples a while ago and wrote them down, but don't remember if they are correct or not:

   ```
   1[c[1]];
   26[p];
   ```

   Would either of those be equivalent to `c[1][1]`?

I know a lot of this is very basic, but I'm having trouble finding sources that address these specific instances online.

Thanks!

Comment: Change second line to int **p;

Comment: The error: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int [5][25]' to 'int **' results.

Comment: In some cases `c[0][24]` will be followed by `c[1][0]` if accessed in memory sequence, but nothing really guarantees that. I suppose the compiler is free to choose how it will store those matrixes, therefore making assumptions may lead to undefined behaviour.

Comment: What would be the equivalent notation to access c[1][1] in the format *(c+27)? @Havenard

Comment: In this case, `*(c+26)`

Comment: Note that this is only possible because you declared it as a static matrix. Usually matrixes are built as arrays of pointers to arrays, so they can be passed as parameter to other functions. Its the case of the parameter `argv` in `main()`. When made this way you cannot access the values in sequence like that.

Comment: @Havenard, arrays are guaranteed to be stored contiguously in row-major order

Comment: @MattMcNabb Yes, but we are not talking about arrays here are we?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Q:** 1.) Did I declare the second line correctly?

**A:** No, you did not. The correct way would be:

```
int (*p)[25] = c;
```

**Q:** 2.) Would `*(c+26)` access the array at `c[1][1]`?

**A:** No. `*(c+26)` is same as `c[26]`. In your case, it will lead to undefined behavior since the array index, `26` is not valid for your array.

**Q:** 3.) Can you access `c[1][1]` by doing something like `c[2][-24]`?

**A:** No, you cannot. Use of array indices that are out of bounds will lead to undefined behavior.

**EDIT**
Even though `-24` appears to be an out of bound array index, using `c[2][-24]` appears to be same as using `c[1][1]`. I retract my first answer.

**Q:** 4.) Would you be able to access `c[1][1]` by the statement `p[1][1]`?

**A:** Yes, you can if you change the declaration of `p` to the way I have done it.

**Q:** `1[c[1]];` and `26[p];`

Would either of those be equivalent to c[1][1]?

**A** `1[c[1]]` is equivalent to `c[1][1]`. `26[p]` is equivalent to `p[26]` but it is not equivalent to `c[1][1]` regardless of whether `p` is defined your way or my way.

Comment: When declaring int** p = c, The error: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int [5][25]' to 'int **' results. However, as Tejas Patel showed me int (*p)[25] = c, doesn't throw an error. Will declaring it this way affect your answers to my questions?

Comment: @user3421751 That is indeed an error. I fixed that.

Comment: Using both your input and Havenard's input, on question 2, *(c+26) will result in c[1][1] **iff** the matrix is static, otherwise it will throw an exception? @R Sahu @Havenard

Comment: @user3421751 `c+26` is same as `c[26]`. `*(c+26)` is same as `*(c[26])`, which is same as `c[26][0]`. As you can see, this is clearly out of bounds access.

Comment: @R Sahu you got confused , `*(c+26)` is the same as `c[26]`.

Comment: Q3: Is it really out of bounds? It is inside the already declared object, so the addresses will be `(char*)&c + 2 * sizeof(c[0]) - 24 * sizeof(c[0][0]) = (char*)&c + 2 * 25 * sizeof(int) - 24 * sizeof(int)` resp. `(char*)&c + 1 * sizeof(c[0]) + 1 * sizeof(c[0][0])` = (char*)&c + 1 * 25 * sizeof(c[0][0]) + 1 * sizeof(c[0][0])` which both makes `(char*)&c + 26 * sizeof(int)`. That clearly lies within the bounds of `c`.

Comment: @glglgl Thanks for the explanation. I have added an EDIT to my answer.

Comment: @glglg `c[2][-24]` exceeds the bounds of the array `c[2]`. It doesn't exceed the bounds of `c` but that doesn't matter. If the compiler does bounds-checking it could trap on this

Comment: @MattMcNabb Nevertheless, it is as valid as doing other pointer arithmetics: `int i[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}; int * p = i + 3; printf("%d\n", p[-2]);` is well-defined. And the situation we talk about is in priciple the same.

Comment: It's not valid. In `p[-2]` the object in question is the array `i`, that is whose bounds are relevant, because `i + 3` is a pointer into the array `i`, so `p[-2]` is OK. In `c[2][-24]`, `c[2]` is the object in question (it decays to `&c[2][0]` which is still a pointer into `c[2]`) and the valid indicates are `0` through `24`.

Comment: C99 6.5.5#8 is the relevant section. "If the pointer operand points to an element of an array object"  -  `&c[2][0]` points to an element of the array object `c[2]`. This pointer has type `int *` so it cannot point to an element of `c` (those elements have type `int[25]`).